# Unable to access UEFI BIOS setup or boot into Windows after setting MBR with EasyBCD then resetting it

Tags: windows-8, bootloader, mbr, bcd, easybcd

I can't exactly remember what the menu items were called (because I can't boot into my computer), but I'll try my best.

Earlier I tried using EasyBCD with Windows 8 on a UEFI Lenovo IdeaPad Z580 laptop to add a boot loader option for Linux Mint. It didn't boot into Mint, and so booted back into Windows and, in EasyBCD set the MBR with the first option checked (Windows Vista/7 bootloader) clicked "Write MBR". I was still unable to boot into Mint, and I noticed that I could no longer access the BIOS/UEFI settings.

If I click the "Novo" button while the laptop is off I boot to a "Novo Button Menu":

```
┌──────────────────┐
│ Novo Button Menu │
├──────────────────┤
│  Normal Startup  │
│    BIOS Setup    │
│     Boot Menu    │
│  System Recovery │
└──────────────────┘
```

The first three items would all just boot into Windows, I didn't try the fourth (I'll get onto System Recovery later).

In the Windows 8 boot menu I opened command prompt and ran `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` to try restore the normal Windows bootloader and the BIOS options, but this did not work.
Then booted back into Windows again and opened EasyBCD. I went to "BCD Backup/Repair", selected "Reset BCD configuration" then clicked "Perform Action". The program said I needed to create at least one bootloader item, so I created a "Windows" one and set the drive to "C:", saved and rebooted. Whenever I rebooted, I was faced with a similar screen to when I tried to boot Mint with the Windows bootloader:

```
Windows failed to start.
[snip]
File: \BCD
Status: 0x0000098
Info: the Boot Configuration Data file doesn't contain valid information for an operating system.
```

now the first three Novo menu items do this, too. The last item opens Lenovo's "OneKey Recovery", which isn't really that useful since it requires a previous backup or a complete restore to a factory state.

How can I boot back into Windows now? I don't have a Windows 8 recovery disc. Is it too later to create one? My laptop has the Windows 8 serial built in (not printed on case).

Comment: You can try deleting the BCD and running `bootrec /RebuildBcd` as detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) from a [Win7 DVD](http://superuser.com/questions/78761). *If* it works (I don't think the BCD format has changed in Win8) it might allow you to boot into Windows at least, although quite likely with the Win7 non-GUI bootloader. Best option of course would be to attempt this with a borrowed Win8 Core/Pro DVD, or one of the [Recovery DVDs sold by the EasyBCD guys](http://neosmart.net/EasyRE/). The [Enterprise Eval](http://goo.gl/yYJ1h) *might* also work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try this and get back to you ASAP, possibly tomorrow.

Comment: I've finally booted into Windows again, however only after a complete "system recovery" with Lenovo's tool. I'll write up an answer to this question now.

Comment: So in other words you started off afresh with factory Windows install using the recovery partition?

Comment: Yeah, but only because I was unable to boot from a USB device without removing the hard drive (since I was unable to access boot menus), and then inserting the hard drive after booting wouldn't mount it (even under Linux). I eventually went ahead and used the "System Recovery" option. Only later did I find out that holding F2 while powering up would go to the BIOS configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) change path of loader to "\Windows\system32\winload.efi"

This is the screenshot of a standard Windows 8 loader (menu policy is set to legacy - text boot menu)

[image: Windows 8 loader]

You can also change path of loader using bcdedit.exe on command prompt:

**bcdedit /set {default} path \windows\system32\winload.efi**

**Addition** how to boot/repair non-booting Windows 8 (request from user Karan):

You can always download the 32/64 bit version of Windows 8 Evaluation iso corresponding to your installed Windows 8 bit version (it is either 32 bit or 64 bit !).

Burn iso to DVD or USB (USB must be formatted in FAT32 for be UEFI bootable!)

Boot DVD/USB (using UEFI way if your HDD is GPT style ! else use BIOS/compatible way) and go to command prompt.

Execute these commands:

**bootsect /nt60 ALL /MBR** ( this will write all boot sectors and MBR even on GPT disk ! Does not harm GPT disk/partitions !!! )

**bcdboot c:\windows** assuming Windows 8 is installed on c:, else change drive letter to map drive where Windows 8 is installed. Simple check is folder c:\Windows exists (execute command - **dir drive_letter:\windows** - e.g. dir d:\windows)

Comment: EasyBCD is not UEFI capable. (at least v.2.2)

Comment: You might want to include in your answer just how someone should run your program on a non-booting Win8 system.

Comment: Added way to repair Windows 8 booting using free downloadable Windows 8 Evaluation.

Comment: Ah, you added how to use WinRE commands from the Enterprise Eval (something I too had [mentioned above](http://superuser.com/questions/605421/unable-to-access-uefi-bios-setup-or-boot-into-windows-after-setting-mbr-with-eas/605487?noredirect=1#comment747675_605421)). Since your initial  recommendation was to use your Visual BCD Editor with a nice UI, I was hoping you'd add steps on how to use it from a WinPE 4.x LiveDVD/USB.

Comment: I would not recommend running Automatic StartUp Repair as Windows 8 Evaluation is Enterprise flavor so the outcome against just Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro is not clear.

Comment: You're right, no idea what Automatic Repair will do since the version's different (might make for a nice experiment though!), but I guess bootrec (which I mentioned above), bootsect, bcdbood (which you did) run manually from WinRE should work fine...

Comment: Karan, VisualBCD beside .NET uses some standard dialog boxes not available in PE4 - have to fix it. But I think people on reboot.pro will come with a general solution, so we will be able to run almost any program in PE4.

Comment: Nice, looking forward to a fixed version or an alternative solution. BTW, is VisualBCD currently fully portable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9194/discussion-between-snayob-and-karan)

Comment: @snayob https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/system-requirements/ says otherwise

Comment: @ike - you can put another comment in the year 2020. Which version is UEFI capable as of May 2015 ? I don't trust what Neosmart is writing in their wiki - only real tests can prove capability or functionality.

Comment: @Karan - what about Windows 8 installed to USB (Windows 2go). Visual BCD Editor could run there;)

Comment: https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/ also explicitly says that it can work (but not by default). I'm not going to mess with a bootloader just to prove that it works. It says 2.2 is capable.

Comment: I don't trust blindly writings of people/companies proved to cheat - example Neosmart "easyldr" = renamed ntldr - Microsoft product.